# How to inject bean validator automatically enabled by JPA?

Tags: spring, validation, jpa

I have a spring application with JPA. I'm using JSR303-Bean validation framework.

> http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2461
>
> 6.2.2. JPA
>
> If you are using JPA 2 and Hibernate Validator is in the classpath the
> JPA2 specification requires that Bean Validation gets enabled.

What the documentation says is true, jsr303 works as expected. I want to do unit tests on the constraints. My unit tests are spring enabled, so autowiring should work. The problem is I can't autowire the javax.validation.Validator since it is not managed by spring.

How should I get a reference to the validator object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` which is managed by Spring. For example in your test `applicationContext.xml` add the following:

```
<bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

And then you can get a handle on the `Validator` inside your test class via an autowired field (Spring will resolve the actual provider):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class ValidationTest {

    @Autowired
    private javax.validation.Validator validator;

    @Test
    public void testValidation {
        // Run validator.validate() on your entity and perform assertions
    }
}
```